# How to specify column type and length for a derived column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a derived column that does not fit within the default varchar(255) so i want to make it a mediumtext. How can that be achieved?

```
 create table app_meta_v as select concat_ws('|',a.platform,
   category,category_level,appid) rowkey (mediumtext) from app_meta;
```

The mediumtext is of course a syntax error: what is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the column type in the create table part, and then just select the value *using the same column name* to get it inserted in the matching column;

```
CREATE TABLE app_meta_v (rowkey MEDIUMTEXT) AS 
  SELECT CONCAT_WS('|',a.platform, category, category_level, appid) rowkey
FROM app_meta;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special.  CONCAT_WS automatically sizes the column to match the longest string in the data.

Example:

```
create table abc(def varchar(255));
insert into abc values ('abcdefghijkl');
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
update abc set def=concat(def,def);
select * from abc;
```

At this stage, you can see "def" is at the maximum 255 characters.

```
create table abc2 as select concat_ws(',', def, def) def from abc;
```

Then, when you inspect the column def in table abc2, it will show varchar(511)

```
show columns from abc2

------------------------
Field    | Type
------------------------
def      | varchar(511)
```